# JavaScript array.constructor like in python

Tags: javascript, python, constructor

I'm working on a python version of a JavaScript project and came across array constructor and couldn't wrap my head around it for python. my aim is to convert this code to python

```js
copy( source ) {
    this.array = new source.array.constructor( source.array );
    this.count = source.count;
    this.stride = source.stride;
    this.usage = source.usage;
    return this;
}
```

My attempt:

```py
def copy(self, source):
    self.array = source.array.constructor( source.array )
    self.count = source.count
    self.stride = source.stride
    self.usage = source.usage
    return self
```

how do I convert this line `this.array = new source.array.constructor( source.array )` to python. `source.array` is a list or array in javascript.

In JavaScript I know that the constructor property returns the function that created the Array prototype. But How does this work in python?

Comment: `type(source.array)` — But you probably just want to use the existing `deepcopy` module…?!

Comment: @deceze does this mean that this line `this.array = new source.array.constructor( source.array );` is checking the `type` of the array? please can you explain futher

Comment: That line gets the class which was used to instantiate `source.array`, and calls it to make a new instance, passing it the current `source.array` as argument. The equivalent in Python would be something like `type(source.array)(source.array)`. But again, the overall task here is what Python's `deepcopy` already does…